What reasons are there to not enable the service broker?
I like to enable the Service Broker on all of my non-system databases. I'd probably put it in model, but I recall something preventing that.
What reasons are there, no matter how far-fetched, for not enabling the Service Broker everywhere? All that I could find is that it's difficult to grab an exclusive lock in some databases.

I would suggest adding more to your question, such as why you want to enable that feature as a default on all new databases. Instead of having the reader assume why you would want to turn it on and then come up with solutions to why you shouldn't, maybe state the problem you are trying to solve by enabling service broker so others can decide to answer the question.

Service Broker is an optional feature. As with all optional features, the burden is on you to decide if it is worth enabling. The burden is not on us to provide you with a reason to leave things in their default state.
Why is this?
Service Broker isn't special. The approach of leaving features disabled unless you need them applies to broad swaths of IT, including but not limited to SQL, firewalls, routers, and operating systems.
Enabling extra features opens you up to several risks.

Attack surface. More enabled features means more possible ways for a malicious actor to attack your system.
Performance. More enabled features means more demand on your resources, such as CPU, RAM, and disk.
Bugs. More enabled features means more ways in which a bug can be introduced to your environment, causing unexpected behavior.
Uptime. More enabled features means more patches will be applicable to your environment, requiring more patching and more downtime.

If you need Service Broker, go ahead and enable it. But enabling things "just because I like to" isn't a good practice.
